# Adding tag to treenode

Tags: vb.net, treeview

With the below code I'm adding from a list of files in a list box to a treeview. I would like to add a Tag to each of the added nodes that contains its file extension.

I've searched all day and for the life of me can't work out how to add a tag to a treenode

```
      Dim Copy2 = aMailbox & tvProgress.SelectedNode.Parent.Text & "\" & tvProgress.SelectedNode.Text & "\" & lstRequired.Text
    Dim Copy1 = rPath & lstRequired.Text

    If File.Exists(Copy2) Then
        MsgBox("File already added. Please edit from the view above", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If lstRequired.Text = "Add Additional Requirement" Then
        ReportSelect.Show()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If File.Exists(Copy1) Then
        File.Copy(Copy1, Copy2)

        tvProgress.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(lstRequired.Text)
        tvProgress.ImageIndex = 0
    Else
        MsgBox("This file no longer exists in your Lynx Repository. Please select another", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Lynx Control Panel")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Any advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use the `Tag` property of that node.

```
tvProgress.SelectedNode.Nodes(i).Tag = "yourTag"
```

Where `i` is the index of the selected node. You can get that index by using

```
Dim i as index
i = tvProgress.SelectedNode.Index
```

**EDIT:**

```
tvProgress.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(lstRequired.Text)
'try adding this code
dim i as integer
i = tvProgress.SelectedNode.Nodes.count - 1
tvProgress.SelectedNode.Nodes(i).Tag = "yourTag"
tvProgress.ImageIndex = 0
```

Comment: Thanks however `Dim i as index
i = tvProgress.SelectedNode.Index` is giving me an error of `System.data.index is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'` - just trying to work through that now

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but I have another alternative : get the node count of the selected node and make it as an index, I'll edit my answer.